# Help me with my page, when open this page shows me this:

Tags: 7, database

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 145 Table './mapibrasil/watchdog' is marked as crashed and should be repaired: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => file [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => The file permissions could not be set on %uri. [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => a:1:{s:4:"%uri";s:18:"public://languages";} [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => http://brasil.machupicchu.biz/ [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 190.237.102.164 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1403795901 ) em dblog_watchdog() (linha 160 de /srv/www/machupicchu.biz/public_html/modules/dblog/dblog.module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a drupal question, but you need to repair your table in the MYSQL database, if you can access the db server via command line:

```
REPAIR TABLE <table name>;
```

Otherwise, tools like phpmyadmin have repair tools, check this tutorial: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin_optimize_database.htm

Comment: Also make sure you disk isn't full.  That could have caused the problem in the first place.